# Fog - Get size of object in S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, fog

How can I get the size of an s3 object in fog without downloading it?

For example:

```
connection.get_object(dir.key, latest_backup.key).body.size
```

requires I download the object first.

How can I find out the size before downloading?

Comment: Did you try accessing the metadata of the object trough the `metadata` method ?

Comment: I didn't know there was one. I can't see it in the docs either... Could you provide an example or docs link? Cheers.

Comment: Ho sorry I thought I had given you the link, here the one I found : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html , this site sucks so I can't give you the exact link, but in the s3, section, there's a list of method on 'S3Object', and it says theres a metadata method

Comment: @pjam - aws-sdk isn't fog.

Comment: @pguardiario indeed, my bad, I quickly read the question and didnt see it wasnt aws-sdk ;

Comment: I know, unfortunately I'm not sure fog has an equivalent...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the size of the file do this:

```
connection.head_object(bucket_name, object_name, options = {})
```

And look for this in the object that comes back:

```
Content-Length
```

This will also give you other good information like the checksum in ETag and other things like that.

Reference: http://rubydoc.info/gems/fog/Fog/Storage/AWS/Real#head_object-instance_method

Answer (score 1):

`remote_file.content_length` does the trick for me (Fog 1.21.0)

where `remote_file` is gotten from the remote directory, like so:

```
def connection
  Fog::Storage.new(fog_config)
end

def directory
  connection.directories.get(bucket)
end

def remote_file
  remote_files = directory.files.last
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```rb
module S3
  def self.directory
    connection.directories.new(key: ENV['AWS_BUCKET'])
  end

  def self.connection
    Fog::Storage.new(
      provider: 'AWS',
      aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      region: ENV['AWS_REGION']
    )
  end

  def self.file(key)
    directory.files.head(key)
  end
end
```

```
file = S3.file(key)
file.content_length
```